# Importing SASS Bootstrap into React

Tags: reactjs, webpack, sass, bootstrap-4

I followed by instructions included in Bootstrap documentation https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/download/#npm and installed Bootstrap via Webpack. 
        Then I wanted to import css styles as here https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/theming/ AND 
        I'VE ENCOUNTERED A PROBLEM:
        When I adding this import `(@import "node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";)` to my custom.scss file and order `sass --watch custom.scss:custom.css` in the console I'm getting this two errors:

```
     1) Error: Cannot find module
     "-!../../node_modules/css-loader/index.js?{"importLoaders":1}!../../node_modules/postcss-loader/lib/index.js??postcss!../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss"

     2)./src/tu_sassy/custom.css Module not found: Can't resolve
     '../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss' in
    '/home/zebra/Desktop/testowa/src/tu_sassy'
```

My file structure is similar as in Bootstrap documentation, included as screenshot below.

!For more I need to add that when I delete this import from custom.scss everything works like a charm ...AND is still reusable and non-corrupted to original Bootstrap stylesheet 'my own stylesheet' WHY ?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3):

One quick tip up front. If you want to write inline-code within your StackOverflow post, use backticks (`) around the code. That makes reading your post much easier.

Sass has its own functionality to import from node modules. Webpack Sass loader provides the ~ (tilde) prefix as a way to tell the compiler that it should resolve the path out of the node_modules folder.

```
@import "~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";
```

If you have a dependency tree of packages within node_modues that import sass files, you can also tell Webpack Sass loader to include node_modules for resolving paths:

```
{
  loader: "sass-loader", // compiles Sass to CSS
  options: {
  includePaths: [
    join(dirname(module.filename), 'node_modules')
  ]
}
```